# c++: unexpected result of const char* in struct array assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

c++: unexpected result of const char* in struct array assignment

my code:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    const char* name;
    const char* out;
} thread_info;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int err = 0;
    std::vector<thread_info> info_vec;
    info_vec.resize(10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //info_vec[i].id = i;
        info_vec[i].name = to_string(i).c_str();
    }
    
    int count = 10;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        /* code */
        //cout << info_vec[i].id << endl;
        cout << info_vec[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

result is :

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

asking for explaination why the result is not "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
what's the problem of my code?

asking for explaination why the result is not "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
what's the problem of my code?

ps:if i use id instead of name, it can print the "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

Comment: Congratulations! You've created a undefined behavior factory.

Comment: Program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You can't expect sane results from broken programs.

Answer (score 7):

`to_string(i)` is a temporary, so the content is freed(or **its lifetime has ended**) after `info_vec[i].name = to_string(i).c_str();`, i.e. the pointer is **dangling**.

Theoretically, dereferencing freed pointer is UB, i.e. anything can happen. Practically, as what your compiler chooses to do(**this is not portable**[^1]), they are all `9` because they all point to the same place; and that's because every string is allocated, and then deallocated, and the next string is allocated at the same place, etc. The final string is `9`, thus you get `9` here. However, since the final string is also deallocated, if some other contents occupy this memory, `9` will also be overwritten.

What you need to do is to make e.g. `name` `std::string` instead of `const char*`, which will hold the content because you **copy it** to another place.

[^1]: As @Chris said, since it's UB, dangling pointers that seem to point to the same place may get different content.

Comment: The fact that in this case all of the pointers point to the same location does not mean this is not undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means _anything_ can happen. The "theoretically" in this answer is potentially misleading.

Comment: @Chris Right, I've changed my wording!

Answer (score 1):

While [o_oTurtle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76832783/15261315) is correct, the core message has to be that the memory has to outlive the scope of the loop iteration to avoid undefined behavior. This doesn't require that the struct member be a `std::string`.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string s = to_string(i).c_str();
        info_vec[i].name = new char[s.size() + 1];
        std::size_t len = s.copy(info_vect[i].name, 0, s.size());
        info_vect[i].name[len] = '\0';
    }
```

Note also that in C++ you don't need the typedef.

```
struct thread_info {
    int id;
    const char* name;
    const char* out;
};
```

And if your struct will contain raw pointers to dynamically allocated memory, you likely want to define a destructor (along with possibly constructors, assignment operators, etc.)